# Matching Names in a column to another dataset's rows in a column

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I'm looking to see how I can join one data frame to another based on the names in a specific column

For example:
DF1 is:

| Name | Fruits | Table |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Apple | Two |
| Megan | Apple | Three |
| Joe | Grape | One |
| Yu | Tomato | Three |

I have another DF2 that has:

| Invite | Age | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RSVP | 21 | John |
| RSVP | 12 | Yu |
| Guest | 19 | Joe |
| Guest | 10 | Joseph |

I want to compare the DF2$Name in DF2 to match the names in DF1, even though it is out of order, and then based on what names match, to create a new data set that includes the Invite and Name status on the left join of DF1 (exclude age), so end result would look like:

DF3: (the info for each persons name will follow suit and be part of that row as well)

| Invite | Name | Fruits | Table |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RSVP | John | Apple | Two |
| RSVP | Yu | Tomato | Three |
| Guest | Joe | Grape | One |

*(Joseph from DF1 is not included because it did not have any match with DF2)

Hopefully this makes sense.
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `inner_join`

```
df2 %>%
  inner_join(df1, by = "Name") %>%
  select(-Age)

  Invite Name Fruits Table
1   RSVP John  Apple   Two
2   RSVP   Yu Tomato Three
3  Guest  Joe  Grape   One
```